# How can I draw circle through XML Drawable - Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to draw circle with the help of XML file in android, but circle is not displaying properly. Below code is showing Oval. How can I create circle in XML file.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"> 
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip" />

</shape>
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not displaying properly"? Do you mean that it is showing an oval rather than a circle?

Answer (score 15):

no need for the padding or the corners.

here's a sample:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

based on :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10104037/878126