# how to fix Scale of android drawable in running

Tags: android, drawable

The problem is my drawable background is not showing as android Designer

my project contain this

```
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BloodType"
            android:layout_width="40px"
            android:layout_height="40px"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

and this is circle.mxl

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<gradient
    android:endColor="#ffffff"
    android:gradientRadius="10"
    android:startColor="#ff0522"
    android:type="radial"></gradient>
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000000"></stroke>
```

can any one Help me 
because I'am new to android devolopment

[this image showing the difference between designer and real running and may show problem if you cant understand me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbj6W.jpg)

thanxx advance ...

Comment: i don't understand with `android:innerRadius="1000dp"` in your code.

Comment: IGNORE THAT LINE FOR NOW THIS FOR TESTING ONLY AND IT NOT IMPORTANT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem by make it proggramaticlly thanks for you

Like this

```
 GradientDrawable g = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR, new int[]{Color.rgb(255, 10, 40), Color.WHITE});
    g.setStroke(1, Color.BLACK);
    g.setShape(g.OVAL);
    g.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
    g.setGradientRadius(X);
    View.setBackground(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have oval shape drawable, and setting this drawable with a textview which has equal height and width. So it behave's like a circle.

See here : [How can I draw circle through XML Drawable - Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209725/how-can-i-draw-circle-through-xml-drawable-android)

Comment: i don't mean the this type of difference i mean  the difference between stroke size and gradientRadius