# OutOfMemory when having many images in the screen

Tags: android, drawable, out-of-memory, android-drawable

I have an activity in my Android application like the image below:

[image: my screen]

legend:

- gray: background image covering the whole screen;
- blue: 5 different sized circles;
- green: an arbitrary image;

I was animating the circles using the View Animation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) to show only one at time.

But I got OutOfMemory exception in some devices and emulators that I used to test.

I changed my layout to use 3 ImageView instead, one with one image of the 3 inner circles, and the others with the 1 outer circle each using the same image file but with different sizes, and I am animating them enabling and disabling their visibility property. Thus I'm using only 2 images instead of 5.

With this approach I stopped getting OutOfMemory exception, I guess because I am loading and displaying less images than before.

FYI, I have different image sizes placed in the folders:

- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-xhdpi

Is the memory that limited? 
Has anyone have a better solution to suggest so I can keep using my 5 circle images?

The application is small so there is no point in going to the path of using OpenGL.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you scaling your arbitrary image or are you just throwing an image at the ImageView?

Comment: Hi, I'm not scaling it.

Comment: Well that's probably why you are getting OOM exceptions. If the image you are using for the arbitrary image is large and you are displaying it as a smaller image, you should most definitely scale it down to preserve memory. [Take a look](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Actually when I said "arbitrary image" I meant that the image wasn't important for the context of this situation. It is a static image and I have different sizes of it in the hpdi, ldpi, mdpi and xhpdi folder.
The issue is with the circles.

Comment: In that case, I would just create a custom View that draws the circles or whatever other shapes you need and avoid using Bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Android system only guarantees 16MB of memory for one application, but manufacturers can allow more (usually they do). But they are not restricted to do so, so if you exceed this limit, you can get `OutOfMemoryException` on a lot of devices with low memory.

Comment: It seems too restricted for a small quantity of images, although they have a big dimension. I wanted to hear from people that passed through  the same situation and came out with a different solution.

Comment: I've passed through by not using so big images on one screen at the same time. If you can use just one image for the circles, do it, I've done it by merging them in the code, and also try to check available memory of device, and load pictures depending on the retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really just circles, you won't need actual bitmap images for them but can use a `ShapeDrawable` instead. This would save all the memory for the circle images (and would result in perfect circles in all resolutions).

A simple example from [another SO item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103900/how-to-get-round-shape-in-android):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Actually they are not just circles, it was just for the sake of simplicity. Thanks anyway!