# Simplest way to create a Shape in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the easiest way to create a Circle in Android Studio (1.2)?

I understand I can do it through using canvas code or writing XML code somewhere, but this seems really complex. None of the guides on the internet seem to provide a simple way. Simple would be drag-and-drop from the menu in Design view of Android Studio, jus tlike widgets.

Been searching for all of today, you can imagine how frustrating this incredibly simple thing is.

Comment: you mean like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103900/how-to-get-round-shape-in-android ?

Comment: "Simple would be drag-and-drop from the menu in Design view of Android Studio, jus tlike widgets" -- the number of things that Android Studio does not do is infinite. Part of that infinity is offering a GUI editor for shapes. "you can imagine how frustrating this incredibly simple thing is" -- if you mean that writing shape XML is "incredibly simple", then it would make sense that the tools team would focus on other areas in Android Studio first. If you mean that writing a GUI editor for shapes is "incredibly simple", feel free to write one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to create a circle in Android is using XML drawable.

They don't have an exact circle shape, but oval shape will do the same job

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```