# How to Create Shapes with code in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an Array List and for every Item, in the Array, I want to create a shape with a Title which should be the String in the Array.
The Blocks should be scroled through horizontally.

[image: example]

I dont know how to add shapes with code, do I have to create a drawable and how do I make it scrollable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953855/2065587

Also, to create a shape you can follow this thread: [Simplest way to create a Shape in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831242/simplest-way-to-create-a-shape-in-android-studio)

Then, you can use your shape as a background in your `RecyclerView` item.